# SQL Server Date insert

Tags: sql-server

I have text data to import into SQL Server and the dates are formatted:

'Jul 14 2005 12:00:00:000AM'

Is there a way that SQL Server will import these directly or do I need to write code to translate the data to number "M/D/Y" format ?

Comment: Import from where? And if the destination is a date or datetime column, *STOP* thinking about *format*. SQL Server stores datetime values as numbers, not as `m/d/y` strings.

Comment: SQL Standard date format as far as I'm aware is 'YYYY-MM-DD'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the standard import features, you could tweak the import mapping, but I would simply import the data into holding tables "as-is" and then copy to the end table performing your conversion at that time.

This works perfectly well

```
select CONVERT(DATETIME,'Jul 14 2005 12:00:00:000AM')
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where the source is or how you are importing, but you can convert them using style #9 (assuming the system will always have US English regional settings and users won't have different `SET LANGUAGE` settings):

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, 'Jul 14 2005 12:00:00:000AM', 9);
```

Otherwise, import them into a staging table with those values as strings, and then `INSERT/SELECT` with the convert.